# Multiple ssh keys with git submodules

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I am using an enterprise version of GITHUB.
I am creating an automatic build server for to build our projects.
These projects have submodules.

As this build server is not "me" (it cannot possess my user credentials) , it needs to be able to download the projects from GIT via the github "deploy keys" feature. (per-project read only ssh-keys)

The limitations are:
1. github expects me to log on as ssh://git@mygithubserver.com
2. github enforces a policy where no two projects can share a deploy key (unlike regular user keys which are registered for the entire github server). [side question, what is the reasoning behind this?!]
3. My corporate IT does not allow shared arbitrary accounts: A user is always associated with a person, it cannot belong to a server.

As such, I think my only option is to use the deploy keys feature with different keys for different projects. (deploy keys were basically developed with this scenario in mind... )

The only way I found which I can setup multiple keys is: https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

Now regarding submodules: This trick can only work for top-level projects, because that's the only place I can specify a custom hostname, as in: "git clone git@custom-git-host-name" command.

When it goes to init and update the **submodules**, it uses whatever hostname is in the parent repo (which is the original mygithubserver.com ) . When our devs use their personal keys, this works flawlessly. However, for the build-server which needs different deploy keys for different projects, this fails.

Is there a way to get around this, and have git use different ssh keys for different projects on the same server?

Is there some silly way to have 2 projects share deploy keys? (I am not allowed to modify github source code, as this is a really huge IT managed enterprise githib server)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved it by creating a small script file in the parent project containing the following:

```
git submodule init
ssh-agent sh -c "ssh-add -D; ssh-add some_private_key.pem; git submodule update some_dubmodule"
ssh-agent sh -c "ssh-add -D; ssh-add another_private_key.pem; git submodule update another_submodule"
```

Comment: Had exactly same problem, in .gitmodules i left the original git remote url. I changed the remote url inside the submodule instead.

Comment: Very handy. For anyone wondering what the above does (I did): `ssh-agent` holds your keys, such as those used by git. "If a commandline is given, this is executed as a subprocess of the agent. When the command dies, so does the agent". Lines 2&3 run a new instance of the agent with `sh -c "<commands>"` This will run a new shell in the agent and then execute those commands in that shell. `ssh-add -D` deletes all current identities *on this instance*. `ssh-add <key>` adds just the one identity from that key file. `git submodule update <module>` does the update with that identity.